# как узнать что элемент массива является вложенным массивом

Tags: php

играюсь с php и появилась загвоздка. Нужно перебрать массив и проверить его на наличие вложенного массива. Вот пример:

    `$menuArr = array(//элементы меню
    "элемент1",
    "элемент2",
    array("вложение1","подвложение2"),
    "элемент4",
    "элемент5");
    $menuSize = count($menuArr);
    for($i=0;$i<$menuSize;$i++){
    if($menuArr[$i] != 'array'){
    //тут просто вывод информации
    }
    };`
как узнать что вместо ЭЛЕМЕНТ3 стоит массив? Вот в этом месте:

```
if($menuArr[$i] != 'array'){
      //тут просто вывод информации
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверить тип переменной функцией [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php):

```
foreach ($menuArr as $menu) {
    if (is_array($menu)) {
        // Элемент массива - массив.
    } else {
        // Не массив, в вашем примере значит что это строка.
    }
}
```

Comment: нашел только что другой способ))) можно использовать функцию gettype(), она вернет тип данных, ну а его можно уже сравнивать. Оказалось все очень просто. Спасибо за совет. обязательно попробую.